# What are some of the pros and cons for using SAM vs serverless framework?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I was wondering which approach to use/explore more, I am currently exploring options to choose the best/suitable framework for building microservices on AWS Lambda, and canary deployments is a huge feature (SAM supports it, but serverless dont right now). Following are my questions:

1. In general, what would be pros and cons of choosing SAM over serverless or vice-versa?
2. Can you write SAM in serverless.yaml? Like SAM has some useful features and if we could utilize them in serverless that would be great

Thanks

Comment: Like all things it depends on your use case

Comment: Thanks, I just refined my question a bit. It would be great to know SAM limitation, pros and cons of both approaches

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**AWS SAM**

The focus on the AWS Serverless Application Model(At least for the moment), is to simplify defining AWS Resources related with Serverless Technology Stack (Lambda, API Gateway & etc.) in CloudFormation.

There are several limitations that comes with SAM. Its currently not providing full support for Custom Authorizers in a flexible manner. Also the DevOps tooling and plugins support is minimal compared to Serverless Framework.

Since SAM is native to AWS, support for AWS features will be available in SAM earlier than the Serverless Framework.

**Serverless Framework**

A DevOps Framework which allows to simplify defining and deploying AWS, Azure, Google Cloud and IBM Open Wisk in an unified manner. It uses CloudFormation underneath for AWS Serverless Stack Provisioning and comes with Plugins Eco System as well as simple commands to carryout DevOps tasks.

Serverless Framework has several limitations

- Deploys new API Gateways for each stage.
- Serverless Framework combines all the Lambda functions (If many defined in a single Serverless Project) and deploy all the code for all the functions, unless blacklisted specifically.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. also one more key difference would be that SAM is AWS specific whereas serverless is not vendor specific,